# Scala foldLeft on Maps

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

How do you use Map.foldLeft?  According to the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html) it looks like

```
foldLeft [B] (z: B)(op: (B, (A, B)) ⇒ B) : B
```

But I'm having difficulty:

> ```
> Map("first"->1,"second"->2).foldLeft(0)((a,(k,v)) => a+v )
> ```
>
> error: not a legal formal parameter

The error points to the open bracket in front of k.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want to use the `(a, (k, v))` syntax, you need to advise the compiler to use pattern matching.

```
Map("first"->1, "second"->2).foldLeft(0){ case (a, (k, v)) => a+v }
```

Note that a `case` statement requires curly braces.

Comment: Why is pattern matching required? Are there any other patterns which can be matched for in a foldLeft ?

Answer (score 19):

I think, you can't do the pattern match on tuples as you expect:

```
Map("first"->1,"second"->2).foldLeft(0)((a, t) => a + t._2)
```

Actually, using values and sum is simpler.

```
Map("first"->1,"second"->2).values.sum
```

Comment: He _can_ pattern match on tuples. To pattern match, though, one needs to use `case`.

Comment: @Daniel That's the advantage of my lawyer-like sentence: it's correct (he cannot pattern-match as he expected) but I've forgotten the case syntax.

Comment: For problems like this though, using `values` or `mapValues` is absolutely the clearest solution (which will almost always make it the right choice)

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to use a partial function as the code block, in other words you add a `case` statement that matches on the arguments:

```
Map("first" -> 1, "second" -> 2).foldLeft(0) { case (a, (k, v)) => a + v }
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Theo! This is what I've been looking for a while...but how can `case` be used without `match` keyword and how come is it being used as destructing action?

Answer (score 5):

This is not really an answer to your question but I found it useful when starting out with folds, so I'll say it anyway! Note that the `/:` method "alias" for `foldLeft` can be clearer for two reasons:

```
xs.foldLeft(y) { (yy, x) => /* ... */ }

(y /: xs) { (yy, x) => /* ... */ }
```

Note that in the second line:

- it's more clear that the value `y` is being *folded into* the collection `xs`
- you can easily remember the ordering of the `Tuple2` argument is the same as the ordering of the method "call"